# how to select a particular field and display it's output in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am very confused about the error when i use this code :-

```
<?
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");            
$array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$last = $array['lastactivity'];
echo $last;
?>
```

it doesn't show any output but when i use the above with WHERE username='$user' or any other condition like lastactivity!=0 , it echo's the lastactivity of that user only but i want to display all 'lastactivity' values from that database users that exists in that table.

UPDATE : 
i am also having problem in telling which users are online by storing time(); in lastactivity , i am using this code :-

```
<?
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");            
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$last = $array['lastactivity'];
if(time() > $last+10)
{
echo $last;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not using `<?php ?>` ?

Comment: Have you tried with Google first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");            
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$last = $array['lastactivity'];
echo $last;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this in a while loop, like so:

```
<?
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");

    while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $echo $array['lastactivity'];
    }
?>
```

UPDATE:

Please switch to MySQLi as the MySQLi_* functions are now deprecated. Even better try using prepared statements like this:

```
<?
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost; dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users`");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($result as $item) {
    echo $item['lastactivity'];
    }
?>
```